# Adonis.js WebSocket Room doen't get socket

Tags: adonis.js

I'm starting with Adonis.js framework and I don't undestand how works websocket service. I follow the documentation about this, and try to make a room.

I Let you see :

```html
// app/Ws/Controllers/ChatController.js
'use strict'

class ChatController {

  constructor (socket, request) {
    this.socket = socket
    this.request = request
  }

  * joinRoom (room) {
    console.log(this.socket)   <---- get undefined
  }
}

module.exports = ChatController


// resources/views/welcome.njk

{% extends 'master' %}

{% block content %}
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/adonis-websocket-
client@1.0.2/dist/ws.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const io = ws('', {})
    const client = io.channel('chat').connect(console.log)
    client.joinRoom('index', {}, console.log)
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I load the welcome page, I get "undefined" in console. I don't understand my mistake.

Thank's.

Beru

Answer (score 0):

Hope I am not late.
Update adonis-websocket to 1.0.4 then in the controller modify:

```
* joinRoom (room, payload, socket) {
  console.log(socket)
}
```

Payload is what you send as custom data:

```
client.joinRoom('index', {data}, console.log)
```

Hope it helps.
Let me know if you need any more clarifications.